# iMac Safari web browser

Tags: high-sierra, web-browsing, reading-list

Just updated iMac 2011 model to High Sierra, when I search website it automatically goes into reading. I then have to click that site on reading list to open page as it doesn't open in the normal window as i would expect.

Comment: Please attach a screenshot so that we can better understand your actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset Safari's preferences.

1. Click on “Safari” located in the menu bar in the top left hand
   corner of the screen
2. Click on “Reset Safari...”
3. Place a checkmark beside all available options
4. Press the “Reset” button

If you arent able to reset Safari then you'll have to manually remove some files.

1. Click on the Hard Drive icon located on the desktop
2. Browse to “Users > (Users Home) > Library > Safari folder”
3. Drag every file except “Bookmarks.plist” into the Trash
4. Browse to “User > (Users Home) > Library > Preferences”
5. Locate “com.apple.Safari.plist”,
   “com.apple.internetconfigpriv.plist” and
   “com.apple.internetconfig.plist” and drag them to the trash.
   **NOTE: If “com.apple.internetconfigpriv.plist” does not exist, 
   ignore it and just trash the other two files**
6. Restart Safari